# Buscarv en Python

Tags: python, excel

Estoy intentando hacer un buscarv o vlookup con `Python`.
Tengo dos archivos,
**Libro1** y **Libro2**

Necesito en el **libro2** obtener el `f_id` del archivo 1. 
Mi código es el siguiente y no logro entender por que no funciona

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_excel, merge

df1 = read_excel('Libro2.xlsx')
df2 = read_excel('Libro1.xlsx')

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='sku', how='left')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También les hago referencia al vídeo que estaba mirando para hacer esto
Estos son los dos archivos que tengo. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hHW-g0uSUA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el inicio de los dataframes `df1` y `df2`? (puedes usar `df1.head()`, `df2.head()`) Por otro lado, los ejemplos de código e incluso los _traceback_ con los errores, mejor los pegas como texto y no como imagen, pues de otro modo quien quiera ayudarte y probar tu código no lo puede copiar y pegar, y las trazas de error pueden salir incompletas en una imagen (como es tu caso). Mira [aqui](https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE) como pegar correctamente código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La traza del error, a la cual le falta la parte final que es la que especifica precisamente la excepción, nos da una buena pista:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     ....
>     raise KeyError(key)
> KeyError: 'GRID'
> ```

**el problema es que `Libro1` no tiene la columna `GRID`, la columna se llama `sku`**, las columnas pasadas a `on` tienen que estar presentes en ambos DataFrames.

Tienes varias posibilidades para solventarlo, por ejemplo:

- Renombra la columna `sku` en el DataFrame de Libro1 a `GRID` para que coincidan en ambos DataFrames:

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  df1 = pd.read_excel('Libro2.xlsx')
  df2 = pd.read_excel('Libro1.xlsx')


  df2.rename(columns={"sku": "GRID"}, inplace=True)
  df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='GRID', how='left')
  ```
- Asigna la columna `sku` como índice en el DataFrame de Libro1:

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  df1 = pd.read_excel('Libro2.xlsx')
  df2 = pd.read_excel('Libro1.xlsx')

  df2.set_index("sku",inplace=True)
  df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on="GRID", how='left')
  df3.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
  ```
- Usa los argumentos `on_right` y `on_left`, esto crea también la columna `sku` en el DataFrame final, por lo que debes eliminarla:

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  df1 = pd.read_excel('Libro2.xlsx')
  df2 = pd.read_excel('Libro1.xlsx')

  df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on="sku", right_on="GRID", how='left')
  df3.drop(columns="sku", inplace=True)
  ```